# how to remove js info popup from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I disable this really annoying info popup in VS Code?
Its kind of like Intellisense in that it changes to fit the context of whats being typed.. but its just info and really not helpful.  It pops up over code I'm trying to reference.. and sometimes over the code I'm actively typing.

Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> will dismiss it, but it comes back almost immediately.
I'm looking for a method of permanently disabling this popup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called Parameter Infos and can be controlled using `editor.parameterHints`. Simply set it to `false` in User's Settings.

```
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

I am not sure if it could be done individually for a language.

[Intellisense for VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

HTH

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!